# L-functions and Galois representations: What’s the explicit relation?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

It was mentioned in a lecture on Faltings’s proof of Mordell Conjecture that there’s some kind of correspondence between Galois representation (of cohomology, or some complex of constructible sheaves?) , but it hadn’t been explained explicitly. Also, I’m studying étale cohomology and Weil conjectures. The trace formula also seems suggest that correspondence: Frobenius elements form the Galois group of finite field, and the eigenvalues of them are the zeros and poles of Grothendieck’s L-function. But I can’t see the explicit ‘correspondence’(is there?) and I have no idea about the case of other base field.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The situation is:

One defines an $L$-function associated to a representation $V$ of the Galois group of a number field $K$ as $$L(V,s) = \prod_{ \mathfrak p } \frac{ 1}{ \det( 1 -|\mathfrak p|^{-s} \operatorname{Frob}_{\mathfrak p} , V^{I_{\mathfrak p}} )}$$ with the product taken over the primes of $K$, where $V^{I_{\mathfrak p}}$ are the inertia invariants of $p$ (which, for all reasonable Galois representations agree with $V$ away from finitely many primes).

So there is a correspondence between $L$-functions and Galois representations simply by definition.  One can check that if two Galois representations over the rational numbers have the same $L$-function, then they have the same characteristic polynomial of Frobenius at each place, and if in addition they are semisimple, then they are isomorphic. So in some cases this is a one-to-one correspondence.

Furthermore one can define, associated to a scheme $X$ over $\mathcal O_K$, the Hasse-Weil zeta function. This definition doesn't reference Galois representations at all, and just refers to the closed points of $X$. However, one can check using the Lefschetz fixed point formula (applied to the fiber of $X$ over each finite field) that the Hasse-Weil zeta function is

$$ \prod_i  L( H^i (X_{\overline{K}}, \mathbb Q_\ell), s)^{(-1)^i} $$ up to changing factors at finitely many primes (the primes where $X$ has singularities and the primes dividing $\ell$).

The zeta function appearing in the Weil conjectures is the Euler factor of the Hasse-Weil zeta function at a particular prime, and the proof of this is almost identical to the proof of the expression of the Weil zeta function in terms of cohomology in the proof of the Weil conjectures.

Comment: Nice answer, but for the definition of $L(V, s)$, you need to special-case the ramified primes (and the primes dividing $\ell$ if $V$ is $\ell$-adic).  The simplest solution is probably to take product over $\mathfrak{p} \notin \Sigma$ for some large enough finite set of primes $\Sigma$, and define HW zeta function to count closed points of residue char not in $\Sigma$.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Good point, thanks.

Comment: Some issue for $\mathfrak{p} \mid \ell$ still?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler The definition I give makes sense for $\mathfrak p$ dividing $\ell$, I thought, it just doesn't give the optimal local factor. (It detects all the Frobenius eigenvalues of weight $0$, I think). So it's not the best $L$-function, but it's at least as good as not giving the factor. And then I say there can be extra factors at primes dividing $\ell$ in the HW eqiality.